# R : Can I use Mydata$variable[i] in my for loop?

Tags: r

there

I have a `variable <- c("apple", "banana", "orange")`, and I also have a dataframe `Mydata` with `colnames(Mydata) <- c("apple", "banana", "orange")`.

I want to write a for loop. Can I write it in this way?

```
for (i : length(variable)){
     Mydata$variable[i] == ......
}
```

This is just an simple example, the data in my hand is much more complicated. If I use `Mydata$variable[i]`, R would tell me there is not any column named `variable[i]`.

What should I do to actually make this happen? Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: this is a duplicate. You need `Mydata[[variable[i]]]`

Comment: It works! Thank you so much.